# php.ini set dynamic folder path with current date for xdebug.log

Tags: php, logging, dynamic, xdebug, filepath

So my problem is that my xdebug.log file is too big and so I was thinking of splitting it by one file a day.
I know how to do that manually, but I'd like to know if it was possible to set a dynamic path to a new xdebug file through php.ini as it is where the path is defined.
currently I have this:

```
php.ini
xdebug.remote_log="D:\Work\Project\www\xdebug.log"
```

and I'd like to end up with something like this:

```
php.ini
xdebug.remote_log="D:\Work\Project\www\2017\02\23_xdebug.log"
```

I do know that there is a possibility to use some variable (I did read the php doc, google after it for severals hours) but I can't really find a clear answer so far about if I can do this, have a workaround or just how to do it!

Thanks in advance!! (if I missed some information to provide just tell me!)

Comment: AFAIK - no -- https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log (no mentions of such options). Maybe use some script that will rename current log at the end of the day/on schedule.

Comment: If there is no solution, that is what I would go for. But I keep hope someone would knows of something!! :D ('cause I'm an optimist!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply went through this with the script solution in the end, using powershell.

Here you can see the function (you can directly add it in your Microsoft.Powershell_profile.ps1 (more info about how to create one here : https://www.howtogeek.com/50236/customizing-your-powershell-profile/)

```
function xdebugsetlogpath {
    # Set directory logs path (year\month)
    $DirPath = ("Path\To\Your\logs\" + (Get-Date -UFormat '%Y\%m'))
    # Set xdebug.log file name (day_xdebug.log)
    $NewFile = (Get-Date -UFormat '%d') + "_xdebug.log"
    # Set full file path
    $NewFilePath = ($DirPath + "\" + $NewFile)
    # Create the folder beforehand as xdebug wont do it itself
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $DirPath
    # Create the file (xdebug can do it but well)
    New-Item $NewFilePath
    (Get-Content C:\PHP712\php.ini) | `
        ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'xdebug.remote_log=.*',('xdebug.remote_log="' + $NewFilePath + '"') } | `
        Set-Content C:\PHP712\php.ini
    # Don't forget to restart service
    httpd -k restart
}
```

After adding it to your profile, simply restart your powershell prompt and type `xdebugsetlogpath` and that it! (don't forget to edit the path where you want to get your logs in!)